# Find the coordinates of the inflexion points of $A(\beta)=8\pi-16\sin(2\beta)$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I tried:

$$A'(\beta) = -32\cos(2\beta)$$
$$A''(\beta) = (-32\cos(\beta))' = 64\sin(2\beta)$$
$$\\$$
$$\\0 = \sin(2\beta) \Leftrightarrow \\ 2\beta = \arcsin(0) +2k\pi \lor 2\beta = \pi -  \arcsin(0) +2k\pi \Leftrightarrow \\ \beta = k\pi \lor \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi
$$

$k \in \mathbb{Z}$

So the coordinates would be $$(a,8\pi), a = k\pi \lor a = \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$$

But my book says the solution is $$(a,8\pi), a = k\frac{\pi}{2},k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: They are in fact the same thing. The second form is terser.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I see. Do you know any trick to convert my answer into my book's one?

Comment: The two equations separated by the or in your answer define two sets of points. Within each set there is a distance of $\pi$ between adjacent points, and between such points lies a point of the other set. Visually, then, it forms one set with separation $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A''(\beta) = 64\sin(2\beta) = 0$

Let $\theta = 2\beta$, then where is $\sin\theta = 0$?

$\theta = k\pi$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$  Thus $\beta = k\frac{\pi}{2}$